# C#, Update access database after adding record

Tags: c#

I'm creating the application with C# visual studio 2012. The problem is when I add new record into access database, my combo box becomes out of date( the value doesn't change after adding or deleting any record). The combo box will be up to date after closing the problem and open it again. So how can i make a "real-time" combo box ?

```
try
        {
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "select AccountNumber from Account";
            //MessageBox.Show(query); for checking
            command.CommandText = query;
            //ExecuteNonQuery() : use for update,delete or instert into the database
            OleDbDataReader reader =   command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read()) //return true
            {
                comboListAcc.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString()); 
            }


            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Many thanks

Comment: Show how you're binding it to the combo box.

Comment: I edit the post and put the code inside

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SqlDependency for this... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency

```
using (SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand("select AccountNumber from Account", connection))
{
    // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
    SqlDependency dependency=new SqlDependency(command);

    // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

    // Execute the command.
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // As you already have for first update
    }
}


void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e )
{
   // Clear and re-add
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You put the data in the first time, why in the world do you expect the box to auto-update?  You're going to have to update it yourself after the change and there's no practical answer for figuring out it needs to be updated if somebody else changes the database.